# Suspend, brightness and power button not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, brightness, hardware

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I am not able to shut down my laptop using the power button as it's not showing any dialog box. I can only force the shutdown of the PC. And after suspending the PC it does not start only shows the blank screen but the laptop remains ON. And also I can't able to change the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behavior of the power button in settings (click on systray icons at the right of the top panel and then settings) choose the power section and from here you can change the behavior of the power button : suspend, power off or nothing.

For suspend issue, does your laptop have a nvidia graphic card?
If it does have one:

you can try to install nvidia's proprietary driver:
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_nvidia_ppa/

Before you follow instructions on this page, don't forget to update and upgrade your system: open a terminal window and then write:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

If the problem remains search for "suspend" on this forum (you are not the only one who has suspend issues)

For the brightness issue: you can change the keyboard shortcuts manually in settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcut. (Although you will probably not be able to use the " fn " key of the keyboard.)

Answer (score 0):

During authorization 22.04, on the upper panel, you can choose to turn off and change the keyboard layout with the mouse, and after pressing return, the mouse buttons no longer function.